# Formatted string parsing and updating

Tags: .net, regex, string

I need to replace specialy marked place holders in string with values. Similar to what string.Format does, but in a bit more advance way.

For instance:
input string: "Welcome to {Binding Path=@city}!" 
Value for @city is "Boston" 
Output string should be "Welcome to Boston!".

I can successfully parse input string with regex and get the values. But to update the string I'm just using string.Replace. I'm currious if there's a better way to handle updates for such scenarious?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Regex.Replace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx), but you really only need it if you see having multiple spots to replace of one match (EX: multiple {Binding Path-@city} in one string).

Comment: If I'll have multiple patterns to replace with diffrent values, Regex.Replace won't work. For instance if input is "Welcome {Binding Path=@name} to {Binding Path=@city}!" this won't work, as will replace all patterns with same value.

Comment: Correct, I was talking about times where you have multiple occurrences of the same string to replace. The match pattern would have to be specific in this case.